# Subquery to get Percentage of Total Sales by Sales Person

Tags: sql-server

Trying to get the sales by SalesPersonID and a Percentage of the Total of all Sales by Year.

Receive error that `OrderDate is not a valid column in T2.OrderDate in Join on` section.  I have set T2 as alias, but it's not working.

```
SELECT Year(OrderDate)
    ,convert(DECIMAL(10, 2), sum(SubTotal + TaxAmt) / T2.TotalSales) AS EmployeeSales
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader T1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Year(OrderDate) AS DateYear
        ,sum(SubTotal + TaxAmt) AS TotalSales
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader T2
    GROUP BY Year(OrderDate)
    ) AS T2 ON T1.OrderDate = T2.OrderDate
GROUP BY T1.OrderDate
    ,T2.TotalSales
WHERE SalesID = 275
```

Comment: In the T2 sub query, you are not selecting the OrderDate, so it is not available out side of the sub query, that is the issue

Comment: I changed it to Select Year(OrderDate) as OrderDate, and i get error The multi-part identifier "t2.OrderDate" could not be bound.  Also getting ambiguous column name on Year(OrderDate) in first Select statement.